# Identify iPad generation by box pictures

Tags: ipad

I found an auction, where someone put a new unpacked device in iPad 1st generation section for corresponding price of iPad 1, while its clear that it is not iPad 1 just by looking at 1st photo included.
The person selling the device didn't write any other informations beside that it has 16GB HDD and is brand new.
I have tried to contact the seller to confirm if this is 4th generation iPad or not, but did't receive any answer from him/her so far.

[image: Front]
[image: Side]
[image: Front]
[image: Side]

Unfortunately seller didn't include photo of box back.(2nd photo shows "layout" of labels on it, but text itself cannot be read)

Now lets become Sherlock Holmes :)

1. 1st photo shows front of the box, which may belong to any Apple
   tablets, besides 1st generation which were packed in different boxes
   with Ipad picture on top, in almost 1:1 scale

   [image: Ipad 1]
2. 2nd photo shows us, that this is Ipad, not Ipad Air or Ipad mini.
3. On 4th photo we can see Apple logo. 3rd generation has ICloud logo
   instead. So we now know this is either 2nd or 4th generation :)
4. There is also one more detail on 4th photo. Apple logo is silver. If am not wrong 2nd gen box has black apple logo instead.

   For 90% this is 4th generation, but not sure. Can you help me decide if this actually ipad 4th by looking at photos above?:)

Comment: @grgarside - I have to beat last year's figure of 20 & I always did like Tom Baker ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an iPad 4 box. You can tell it by the ios5 wallapaper. The ipad 2 has a iOS 4 wallpaper.

Your 3rd point is true : Only the iPad 3 have the iCloud logo. 
Your 4th point if false. iPad 2 have also a silver Apple logo on their boxes.